# Move position of Iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator

I have a class `VirtualMachine`, with an `ArrayList<Consumer<VirtualMachine>>`, which contains commands (`Consumer<VirtualMachine>`) that modify the other fields of the VirtualMachine object. When running, the VirtualMachine calls the next Consumer from the ArrayList.

**I need to modify the position of the iterator in the list of Consumers, from a Consumer.**

Is there a way to do this with ArrayList Iterators, or is there another Collection in Java that can do this? (SE 8 standard library answers preferred over importing a 3rd party library)

Comment: What do you mean "modify the position of the iterator"? Do you mean that you want to change the order of `Consumer` objects in the `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

Transform to `Consumer<VirtualMachine>` to `ToIntFunction<VirtualMachine>` and interpret the returning value as the number of positions the iterator should be moved.

```
ToIntFunction<VirtualMachine> action1 = vm -> {
    // Do the work over vm
    return 1; // Make one step forward
};
ToIntFunction<VirtualMachine> action2 = vm -> {
    // Do the work over vm
    return -1; //Make one step backward
};
ListIterator<ToIntFunction<VirtualMachine>> i = Arrays.asList(action1, action2).listIterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    int count = i.next().applyAsInt(vm) - 1;
    for (; count < 0; count++) {
        i.previous();
    }
    for (; count > 0; count--) {
        i.next();
    }
}
```